# How do I set multiple text styles in an envirnoment defined in a layout file?

Tags: fonts, environments, lyx-layouts

I'm trying to make the font monospace, bold, and small at the same time in an environment defined in my layout file. This seems like a ridiculously simple thing to do, but I've been struggling with this for a few hours now.

Here's what doesn't work:

```
\newenvironment{ogc_chapter_date}{
   \raggedright
   \begin{texttt}
   \begin{small}
   \begin{bffamily}
}{
   \end{bffamily}
   \end{small}
   \end{texttt}
   \par
}
```

The above is in my Lyx `.layout` file.

This is what I get in the log when it fails to compile:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.137 \begin{ogc_chapter_date}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\@ifundefined ...dafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \relax \expandafter \@firs...
l.137 \begin{ogc_chapter_date}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Extra \else.
\@ifundefined ... \expandafter \@firstoftwo \else 
                                                  \expandafter \@secondoftwo...
l.137 \begin{ogc_chapter_date}

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ->\@nil 

l.137 \begin{ogc_chapter_date}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> \egroup 

l.137 \begin{ogc_chapter_date}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{texttt} on input line 137 ended by \end{bffamily}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.139 \end{ogc_chapter_date}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.139 \end{ogc_chapter_date}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `\texttt` macro, which requires a parameter, as an environment name. This leads to the first error. Use `ttfamily` instead. The next thing is `bffamily` which is not defined. The proper name is `bfseries`. You can read about the various font commands in the [LaTeX font guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf).

Also note that the commands you use as environment should be used as switches, like `\ttfamily` instead of `\begin{ttfamily}`, though LaTeX's environment implementation still permits this use.

So I recommend to use the following definition instead (perhaps underscores in environment names should also be avoided).

```
\newenvironment{ogc_chapter_date}{
   \raggedright
   \ttfamily
   \small
   \bfseries
}{
   \par
}
```

Note that environments internally use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` that here limit the scope of the font commands' effects.